# Angular4 jsonp request callback

Tags: angular, jsonp, zone

I am working in migrating an Angular 1 app to Angular 4, there is a jsonp call to an endpoint I don't control.

In the Angular 1 app it is using:

```
jsonpCallback: 'callback'
```

But the endpoint actually returns with 'callback' no matter what callback was in the request. e.g.

```
callback({"result":"123456"})
```

I tried this in Angular4

```
    const searchParams = Object.assign({}, {
        callback: 'callback'
    }, callParams);
    const params = Object.keys(searchParams);
    if (params.length) {
        params.forEach((param: string) => searchConfig.set(param, searchParams[param]));
    }
    const options: RequestOptionsArgs = {
        search: searchConfig
    };

    this.jsonp.request(url, options)
    .subscribe((results) => {
        console.log(results);
    });
```

But I get the error "callback is not defined" on the jsonp response.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this I needed to declare callback on the window object, before making the API call.

```
        window.callback = function(data) {
            //Do stuff here
        }
```